# File open on Snapdragon Flight DSP returning suspiciously large number

Tags: android, c, file-io, real-time, file-descriptor

Why, when calling `open("/dev/tty-2",O_RDWR);` is the open file number 268435355 (eg -1+2^28)? Is this a normal sized number to output from open() call on a real-time operating system (like android DSP side)? It seems too large.

DSP processor running Qualcomm Real-Time OS. Other processor running Linaro Linux.

Pertinent output from `mini-dm`, DSP (digital signal processor) runtime debugger:

```
Running mini-dm version: 3.0
Device found with Product ID 0x9025. Continuing...
mini-dm is waiting for a DMSS connection...
DMSS is connected. Running mini-dm...
[08500/03]  00:40.640  HAP:63:HAP_debug_v2 weak ref not found, return _rtld_sym_zero@_rtld_objmain  0294  symbol.c
[08500/03]  00:40.640  HAP:63:HAP_debug_v2 weak ref not found, return _rtld_sym_zero@_rtld_objmain  0294  symbol.c
[08500/02]  00:40.640  HAP:63:Opening serial port  0062  helloworld_dsp.c
[08500/00]  00:40.640  configuring UART for 4-wire mode, DAL id: 0x2001005  0852  DalUart.c
[08500/02]  00:40.641  HAP:63:Opened serial port number 268435455  0065  helloworld_dsp.c
[08500/02]  00:40.641  HAP:63:Closing serial port  0075  helloworld_dsp.c
[08500/02]  00:40.641  HAP:63:Successfully closed serial port number 268435455  0078  helloworld_dsp.c
[08500/02]  00:40.641  HAP:63:Opening serial port  0062  helloworld_dsp.c
[08500/02]  00:40.642  HAP:63:workaround: reopening an existing serial port  0351  serial.c
[08500/02]  00:40.642  HAP:63:Opened serial port number 268435455  0065  helloworld_dsp.c
[08500/02]  00:40.642  HAP:63:Beginning serial read  0123  helloworld_dsp.c
[08500/02]  00:40.642  HAP:63:/dev/tty-2 read bytes [0]:   0129  helloworld_dsp.c
[08500/02]  00:40.642  HAP:63:Closing serial port  0075  helloworld_dsp.c
[08500/02]  00:40.642  HAP:63:Successfully closed serial port number 268435455  0078  helloworld_dsp.c
```

Pertinent DSP code:

```
int example_interface_serial_open()
{
LOG_INFO("Opening serial port");
  serial_fds[0] = open(serial_path[0],O_RDWR);
  if (serial_fds[0] >= SUCCESS) {
    LOG_INFO("Opened serial port number %d", serial_fds[0]);
  } else {
  //FIXME log error!
LOG_INFO("Error opening serial port");
    serial_fds[0] = ERROR;
  }
  return serial_fds[0];
}

int example_interface_serial_close(int fd) {
LOG_INFO("Closing serial port");

  if (!close(fd)) {
    LOG_INFO("Successfully closed serial port number %d", fd);
  } else {
    LOG_INFO("Error closing serial port");
    fd = ERROR;
  }

  return fd;
}

int example_interface_serial_read(int fd) {
  int res = SUCCESS;
  char rx_buffer[SERIAL_SIZE_OF_DATA_BUFFER];
  unsigned int num_bytes_read;
  int active_devices = 0;
  int runs, i;

  LOG_INFO("Beginning serial read");

  memset(rx_buffer, 0, SERIAL_SIZE_OF_DATA_BUFFER);
  num_bytes_read = read(fd, rx_buffer,
      SERIAL_SIZE_OF_DATA_BUFFER);
  LOG_INFO("%s read bytes [%d]: %s",
      serial_path[0], num_bytes_read, rx_buffer);

  if (res < SUCCESS) {
    LOG_INFO("Closing file %s",
      serial_path[0]);
    close(fd);
    fd = ERROR;
  }

return fd;
}
```

Edit: including definition of `LOG_INFO()`

```
/****************************************************************************
 * Copyright (C) 2015 Mark Charlebois. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in
 *    the documentation and/or other materials provided with the
 *    distribution.
 * 3. Neither the name ATLFlight nor the names of its contributors may be
 *    used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
 *    without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS
 * FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT,
 * INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING,
 * BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS
 * OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED
 * AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
 * LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN
 * ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 ****************************************************************************/
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef __hexagon__
// Debug output on the aDSP
#include <HAP_farf.h>

#define LOG_INFO(...) FARF(ALWAYS, __VA_ARGS__);
#define LOG_ERR(...) FARF(ALWAYS, __VA_ARGS__);
#define LOG_DEBUG(...) FARF(MEDIUM, __VA_ARGS__);

#else
// Debug output on the apps processor
#include <stdio.h>
#define LOG_INFO(...) do{ printf(__VA_ARGS__); printf("\n"); } while (0)
#define LOG_ERR(...) do{ printf(__VA_ARGS__); printf("\n"); } while (0)
#define LOG_DEBUG(...) do{ printf(__VA_ARGS__); printf("\n"); } while (0)

#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Output of 
`int i=-1; LOG_INFO("%d\n",1);`

DSP-side:
`[08500/02] 02:27.822 HAP:24639: -1  0063  helloworld_dsp.c`

Linux-side:
`-1`

Comment: this function: `int example_interface_serial_read(int fd) {` has the local variable: `int res = SUCCESS;`   However, that variable is never updated anywhere in that function, so the code block beginning with: `if (res < SUCCESS) {` will never be executed.  This is probably not what you want.   Also, the function should check that the passed parameter `fd` contains a value that represents a successful open of the serial port

Comment: this line: `if (res < SUCCESS) {` in function:  `example_interface_serial_read()` should be: `if(  0 > num_bytes_read ) {`

Comment: generally, a file descriptor, as returned from a call to `open()` is the index into the file descriptor table.  Normally, this is a very small number like 4.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my logic. As for the file descriptor, why would the number that I am returned be so large as well as positive? That it is positive means that the return value is technically not erroneous.

Comment: what is the definition of the macro: `LOG_INFO()`?

Comment: LOG_INFO is not the problem. On the Linux processor, LOG_INFO() is simply printf(). This still prints -1+2^28.

Comment: I think that LOG_INFO is the problem because the source line is: `LOG_INFO("Opened serial port number %d", serial_fds[0]);`  but that resulted in the line: `Opened serial port number 268435455  0065  helloworld_dsp.c`  I.E. the actual data is  text+a single number, but the output shows text+strange number+single number+ file name  SO, once again, post the definition of LOG_INFO

Comment: Good point. To clarify, LOG_INFO is different depending on the processor. LOG_INFO is essentially printf on the Linux-side. See definition above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a developer of the device:

> The return value from the open() functions is a signed int, and is >=
>   zero for success, and less than zero for failure.
>
> The reason the return value is so large is because it is offset by a
>   known constant of 0x0FFFFFFF.  This is done to differentiate device
>   handles from file system handles (file system handles are always less
>   than 0x0FFFFFFF), which are processed differently in the aDSP code.

Quirky! :P